# Cannot get Begin.Invoke, ObservableCollection and background thread to work

Tags: c#, wpf, multithreading, user-interface, listbox

This might be an easy/stupid question, but I cannot simply get the three things in the title to work. I am following the advice from the following SO answer:
[WPF listbox dynamically populated - how to get it to refresh?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1884838/wpf-listbox-dynamically-populated-how-to-get-it-to-refresh)

> Create an ObservableCollection and set your ListBox.ItemsSource to that collection. Because the collection is observable, the ListBox will update as its contents change.
>
> However, if your real operation is blocking the UI thread, this may
>   prevent WPF from updating the UI until the operation completes
>   (because the WPF data binding infrastructure doesn't get a chance to
>   run). So you may need to run your lengthy operation on a background
>   thread. In this case, you will not be able to update the
>   ObservableCollection from the background thread due to WPF
>   cross-threading restrictions (you can update properties, but not
>   collections). To get around this, use Dispatcher.BeginInvoke() to
>   update the collection on the UI thread while continuing your operation
>   on the background thread.

I created ObservableCollection and attached it to the ItemSource of my ListBox:

```
private ObservableCollection<Employee> employeeList;
searchList.ItemsSource = employeeList;
```

I create a thread and instruct it to run the function that populates the ObservableCollection (I am passing text string and ObservableCollection):

```
Thread thread = new Thread(() => ldapConnector.Search(textbox.Text, employeeList));
thread.Start();
```

ldapConnector is a separate class that I initialized, when I started the program. And then I get the following error (pointing at thread creation line):

> The calling thread cannot access this object because a different
>   thread owns it.

As I understood from that post, I would need to run Begin.Invoke() method right after thread creation like this:

```
Dispatcher.BeginInvoke(new Action(()=>{
    searchList.ItemsSource = employeeList;
}));
```

What I am doing wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: Where do you actually change the ObservableCollection? You should invoke *there*.

Comment: @nvoigt in ldapConnector.Search function. Is it when I use Add() and OrderByDescending() methods that I need to use Begin.Invoke()?